# All faces of the n-dimensional hypercube

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am asked to determine all faces of the $n$-dimensional hypercube
$$C_n = \left\lbrace x\in\mathbb R^n \;|\;\forall i\in\lbrace1\ldots n\rbrace : |x_i|\leq1\right\rbrace $$

I already know that the the $k$-dimensional faces of $C_n$ are defined by $n-k$ equalities $|x_i|=1$. 
So in total there are $2^{n-k}{n\choose k}$ of those $k$-dimensional faces.

I understand how those faces look like and for a fixed particular $n$ I would be able to write them all down one by one, but I am struggeling to write down some general expression for all faces.

Comment: @user1952009 I am looking for *all* faces, the vertices (0-d-faces), the edges (1-d-faces) .... up to the Hypercube itself (n-d-face)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said it all. If you want a set-builder description of each  individual face, you can consider the set $S$ of all functions
$$f:\quad[n]\to\bigl\{\{-1\}, \>[{-1},1]\>,\>\{1\}\bigr\}\ ,$$
and for any $f\in S$ define the face $F_f$ of $C_n$ by
$$F_f:=\bigl\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\in{\mathbb R}^n\>\bigm|\>x_i\in f(i) \ \ (1\leq i\leq n)\bigr\}\ .$$